# How to join a large table (1M+) with a reference table in Teradata?

Tags: sql, join, teradata, large-data

I have the following 2 tables-
*tableA* (3 million rows; this is the "data table")
*tableB* (2300 rows; this is the "reference table")

**Schemas -**
*tableA* - id, field1, field2, field3, num_of_actual_items, num_of_possible_items
*tableB* - field1, field2, field3, num_of_possible_items

**Background**
There are 14000 unique *ids* in *tableA*.
So a [select count(distinct id) from tableA] gives 14000 as the answer.

There are 2300 possible combinations of *field1, field2* and *field3* and all of them with their corresponding *num_of_possible_items* are listed in *tableB*.

*tableA* does not contain entries for an *id* when *num_of_actual_items* for a given "*field1-field2-field3*" combination is 0. **This is what I am trying to fix.**

Ideally *tableA* should have 32,200,000 rows (14000 *ids* X 2300 combinations). The query I have is as follows:

```
select A1.id, A1.field1, A1.field2, A1.field3, A1.num_of_actual_items, 
A1.num_of_possible_items
from tableA A1
union
select distinct A2.id, B.field1, B.field2, B.field3, 0 as 
num_of_actual_items, B.num_of_possible_items
from tableA A2, tableB B
where A2.field1 || A2.field2 || A2.field3 <> B.field1 || B.field2 || 
B.field3
```

The above query will give 2 rows for each *id* and corresponding *field1-field2-field3* combination (one for the real num_of_actual_items and one for the artificially added 0 entry).
In the next step, the duplicate rows can be removed by doing an aggregate (max of *num_of_actual_items*) and the problem is solved.

However, this solution only works when *tableA* has 5000-10000 rows. When I try it with the full 3 million rows, I get an "out of spool space" error.

The above query actually populates a volatile table and I have created an indices on field1,field2 & field3 and also collected stats on all 3.

Any ideas what I can do to optimize/change the query for such large volumes?
I am using Teradata.

Edit: I have added the suggestions by Andrew (limiting rows that don't match) and dnoeth (returning only distinct rows as opposed to all) but still no avail.
I keep running out of spool space.

Comment: Can't you add a constraint to your second query so that you only return rows that don't match?  Something like where `a2.field1 || a2.field2 || a2.field3 <> b.field1 || b.field2 || b.field3`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That change still doesn't help. I ran out of spool space again.

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd query within the union is a CROSS join which results in 2300 * 3000000 rows before the distinct.

You must apply a `distinct` before the join:

```
select A1.id, A1.field1, A1.field2, A1.field3, A1.num_of_actual_items, 
A1.num_of_possible_items
from tableA A1
union ALL
select A2.id, B.field1, B.field2, B.field3, 0 as num_of_actual_items,  
B.num_of_possible_items
from (select distinct id from tableA) A2, tableB B
```

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. Even after tightening up the 2nd query, I run out of spool space.

Comment: You can replace the `UNION` with `UNION ALL`, which will reduce spool usage. If you still run out of spool you should talk to your DBA.

Comment: No dice. In fact, just executing the second query alone causes the spool space to run out. Guess I will just try moving it to Hadoop/Hive and see if it solves my problem. Thanks for the help though.